# How to compare changed values and actual values from table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table using foreach I'm filling the td values. There is a check box when user is changed that value i need to get username.

For example while loading time checkbox value is true. Then user will do uncheck immedetaily i should get the value. Same user same row if user check again(i.e old postion(value)) i shouldn't the values.

My Code:

```
 <table>
 .......
 <tr>Heading 1</tr>
 ........
 @foreach (var getData in Model.DBValue)
 {
  <tr>
  <td>
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => getData.AffectedItemId, new { @id = 
  "AffectedItemIdR" + index, @class = "RChangeEvent", @checked = 
   getData.AffectedItemId })
  </td>
  <td>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => getData.updatedDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { 
  @disabled = "disabled", @id = "SignedDateR" + index})
  </td>
  </tr>
 }
 </table>
```

Question:

If there 100 rows how to get the changed rows values?
Could you please help to solve this?

Comment: You could add an attribute to the check box input, something like hasbeenchecked="false", that is updated when the onchange event happens...onchange check the attribute value before retrieving the username.

Comment: verygood idea thank you so much @BillRuhl